# Excel Filtering/Sorting Complex Duplicate Results

Tags: excel, duplicates, vlookup

I have 6700 rows of data.

3 Columns: Account Name, Business Address, Phone Number.

After tons of Vlookups, I found that I have 67 Account Duplicates, 21 Phone Duplicates, and 22 Address Duplicates.

How do I removed those duplicate without going back and forth and singling them out and deleting them one at a time?

thanks

Comment: Hi,  have you tried the `remove duplicates` button on the DATA tab?

Comment: Sort on the offending column, and look for the duplicates identified? That way you can see if/how to merge other data associated.

Comment: If I select "Column A" (Account Name) and remove Duplicates, will it also remove the duplicate's adjacent Columns "B & C" (Address, Phone)?

Comment: Yeah, when I select a single Column that works but when i select multiple columns or expand the selection I get this error: "This can't be applied to the selected range. Select a single Cell in a range and try again."